Dancing Sword and Hold person/monster interaction
Recently I was approached by one of my players that would like to find a Dancing Sword for his bard (and he will get one) but he wants to know how it will work with hold person/monster.
Does he get the crit because the source of damage (his sword) is within 5ft or is he considered the source of damage therefore the crit doesn't register unless he's within 5ft of the creature?

5e 2014 and 2024 are different games with different rules. Which game are you playing?

currently 2014 but i'm planning to transition to 2024 so advice on both would be appreciated :)

Then please ask as two separate questions, clarifying which edition each is about. We want to keep questions about each edition separate, since they’re different games.

@Black_Anno Thanks clearing up which edition and for your first questions. Welcome. :)  Also there is the Help section in top-right corner with a question mark that has a really good Q&A about how to ask questions or respond to answers in the stack.

The Dancing Sword will land critical hits against paralyzed creatures
The hold person and hold monster spells impose the paralyzed condition on creatures that fail their saving throw against the spell. The paralyzed condition includes the following (PHB, p. 291):

Any attack that hits the creature is a critical hit if the attacker is within 5 feet of the creature.

Your question is whether successful attacks from the Dancing Sword will count as a critical hit, presumably because it's the sword that's within 5 feet of the paralyzed creature rather than the player character.
If we look at the wording of the Dancing Sword item (DMG, p. 161):

You can use a bonus action to toss this magic sword into the air and speak the command word. When you do so, the sword begins to hover, flies up to 30 feet, and attacks one creature of your choice within 5 feet of it. The sword uses your attack roll and ability score modifier to damage rolls.

So that says: "The sword ... attacks one creature ... within 5 feet of it".
It may use your attack roll and ability score modifiers, but it's still it--the sword--making the attack. And the sword is within 5 feet of the paralyzed creature, so as per the paralyzed text (which simply mentions "the attacker" and does not specify if that must be a creature, so I take that to mean that the sword counts as a valid attacker), the hit will become a critical hit.
